# Python : Why won't my sine wave change frequency

Tags: python-3.x, trigonometry

I have a function:

```
def KEY(STEP): #Key Number
    return ((2**(1/12))**(STEP-49))*440
```

And a sine generator :

```
value = math.sin(i*KEY(SEQ[x]))*AMP
```

Where SEQ is a list of integers relating to keys on a keyboard (cycled through by a for loop).

My function outputs the right numbers, but when I use it, it only plays 440 hz scaled to the next octave.

For example, I will type in KEY(50) which returns 466.163... which is correct, but the sine wave won't change frequency. It jumbles its values up on my visual display.

Comment: You definitely need more info, ideally a [mcve].  There isn't any sort of "sine wave" in the code you posted.

Comment: add more code, and the plot of the sine wave if you have plotted it.